# Normal Subgroups and Quotient Groups help

Tags: normal-subgroups, quotient-group

Let $(G, ∗)$ be a group, let $H$ be a normal subgroup of $G$, and let $(G/H, ⋆)$ denote the quotient group of $G$ by $H$.

(a) Prove that if $xH \in G/H$, then $(xH)^m = x^mH$ for all $m ∈ Z$.

(b) Suppose that there is no positive integer $m$ for which $x^m ∈ H$. Prove that $ord(xH) = ∞$.

(c) Suppose that there exists a positive integer $m$ for which $x^m ∈ H$. Prove that $ord(xH) = d$, where $d$ is the least positive integer for which $x^d ∈ H$.

Comment: Welcome  to Maths SX! What did you try and where are you stuck?

Comment: I edited your post to make $\LaTeX$ work, and to bring it into accord with typical mathematical conventions.  Hope I got it right!  Cheers!

Comment: Thank you! That is looking good. I have proven part (a) by doing xH ⋆ xH ⋆ ... ⋆ xH (m times) which gives us ( x * x * ... * x) (also m times).

Comment: But I do not know how to prove part (b) and (c) yet. Anyone could give me a hand?